# How to make stealth stop at the edge of a node in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a stealth from destination node's east **horizontally** to the source node's west. I now can achieve this by adjusting the stealth length (trial-and-error) like so:

```
\draw[stealth-](dest.east)--++(0.31, 0)node[pos=0.5, above=0cm]{\tiny{\textbf{$R$}}};
```

But this nice intersection will collapse once the distance between them varies away from `0.31`.

So I am looking for a way to make the stealth **go horizontally until it reaches the west of `src.west`.**

---

Using @percusse's method, I did the encountered problems when the stealth does not come out at the edge center.

**Both**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, calc, positioning, fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (a) {A node};
    \node[draw,align=center] (b) at (2,1) {Another\\node};
    \draw[-stealth] ($(a.north east)!0.1!(a.south east)$) -- (a-|b.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**and**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, calc, positioning, fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (a) {A node};
    \node[draw,align=center] (b) at (2,1) {Another\\node};
    \draw[-stealth] ($(a.north east)!0.1!(a.south east)$) -- ($(a.north east)!0.1!(a.south east)$-|b.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

are not what I want. I want the stealth **always horizontal**. How may I fix it?

Comment: It's always preferred to have complete minimal example documents instead of code snippets that take some guesswork to complete. What's `dest`? Where does `src` come into play (it's only mentioned in your question, but not in the code)? What TikZ libraries are needed?

Comment: I guess you may be looking for the `edge` path action...

Comment: Why not `\draw[-stealth](source.west) -- (dest.east);`?

Comment: @percusse  Oh, because they are not on the same horizontal level. Doing so will make the stealth not horizontal. I wish for a horizontal one.

Comment: Could you provide a MWE? From the question it is not clear what you are asking. Does the path action `-|` go in the direction you are looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Engaging crystal ball... (please put a minimal example instead of describing it)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (a) {A node};
\node[draw,align=center] (b) at (2,1) {Another\\node};
\draw[-stealth] (a) -- (a-|b.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aaaaah! Yes, that could be what perfectionm1ng wants. Nice clairvoyance! =)

Comment: @Jake  Yes! Exactly! Thanks to both of you! :)

Comment: @Jake In English.... please.... :)

Comment: @percusse: Um, "helderziendheid", according to Google?

Comment: @Jake Heheh, fair enough. I would pretend that I have psychic powers.

Comment: @percusse: [Clairvoyance](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n6XKNbAltqw) here, sir! Oh wait, I think I got the *wrong* definition... `:)`

Comment: Hmmm. Not entirely solved. Please see updated question with workable codes. Thanks! @Jake

Comment: @perfectionm1ng you need to brace the second like `\draw[-stealth] ($(a.north east)!0.1!(a.south east)$) -- ({$(a.north east)!0.1!(a.south east)$}-|b.east);`

Comment: Thanks, I added the `{}` but ended up with these: `! Package tikz Error: + or - expected.` and `! Argument of \tikz@cc@end has an extra }.` and `! Paragraph ended before \tikz@cc@end was complete`.

Comment: Could you please kindly help with the follow-up question above? Manuscript submission deadline very soon. The two stealths still dangle there... Thanks!!!

Comment: @perfectionm1ng it's a little hectic now. if I don't make it this ev3ning please ask a new question.  we have lots of experts here.